# No permissions as "sudo"

Tags: sudo, opensuse

I'm trying to compile something in OpenSuse however I get a Permission Denied.
I've tried with "sudo make" and even logged in with superuser but the same error persists.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Where/when do you get the permission denied? Can you post the error message?

Comment: maybe you could give the exact error message (and a few lines of output before/after)? (Running make as root, other than for installing, is not good practice.)

Comment: sudo make
./mknodedecls.pl > nodes/all.h
/bin/sh: ./mknodedecls.pl: Permission denied
make: *** [nodes/all.h] Error 126

Comment: Please edit the question and tell us what you're doing (exactly) and what output you get. Pasting a bunch of lines concatenated into a single line doesn't make this very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing this error running *anything* with `sudo`, or just when running `sudo make`?  If you are only seeing this problem when running `make`, does is happen on *any* makefile, or just this particular one?

Is your user account listed in the [`sudoers`](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html) file properly?

Comment: I have managed to use sudo before, just when making this sudo make it's happening... The account root is listed there

Comment: @pirezas- You'll have to edit your question and add some more details.  Posting the relevant parts of your makefile and the perl script would be a tremendous help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add yourself to sudoers list?  Type whereis sudoers to find out the file and edit it to see if you're in.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot run `sudo make`, then copy `make` to the path in question and try with the new name:

```
 sudo cp /usr/bin/make ./fake

 sudo ./fake
```